# Fundamental theorem of calculus -differentiation of integral

Tags: calculus

I am working on my microeconomics homework set, which requires me to solve the differentiation of an integral, containing x and p, with respect to p. May I get some advices on how to solve it please?

$$ \frac{d \int_p^1 (x-p)f(x) dx}{dp} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial p}\left(\int_p^1 f(x) (x-p) \, dx\right)=\int_p^1 (-f(x) )\, dx=\int_1^p f(x) \, dx$$
see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) for further details